# How to load(preload) Geojson with JS before start another script?

Tags: javascript, geojson, openlayers-2, json, loading

I need to load my Geojson file before start my script .
I need to load file before start this script :

```
var geojsonPrecitany = false;
var geojson = $.getJSON("./tematicke_vrstvy/tematicka_vrstva.geojson", function() {
    geojsonPrecitany = true;
});
```

Which checked that geojson is loaded ( if loaded geojsonPrecitany = true ).

**OR**

I need the solution how to load geojson file **before** start script with map (in Openlayers v3)

Because the work with geojson in js is asynchronous so i need to have the file peloaded before i start work with them in map script.

Answer (score 1):

Start the map from a function that is called as a callback of your `getJSON` call, i.e.:

```
function initMap(){
   var map = new ol.Map({...});
}

var geojsonPrecitany = false;
var geojson = $.getJSON("./tematicke_vrstvy/tematicka_vrstva.geojson", function() {
    geojsonPrecitany = true;
    initMap();
});
```